# serverside database for iOS and Android app

Tags: android, ios, swift, core-data

I am writing an iOS app. It will store details of something on a server somewhere.

I will write an Android app that will offer the same functionality.

I want to access the same database and retrieve the same data no matter whether it is the iOS or Android app being used.

I would appreciate some "keywords" for a technology that can abstract the back end data store so be something common for both iOS and Android.

If there is an example out there on GitHub a link would help me

Thank you

Comment: Firebase is a good choice

Comment: You are looking for a "Mobile Backend". If you want someone else to run it, you want a Mobile Backend as a Service, or MBaaS. See also parseplatform.org, realm.io, or Amazon AWS MobileHub for more options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any database that meets your data modeling needs and performance requirements, which one you chose should depend on the structure of your data. What you should be doing is building a shared middle tier server that persists your data and provides it to your iOS and Android clients. You probably want to pass the data between the client and the server as JSON documents using the http protocol. This is generally known as a REST api though you have to follow certain design principles to really be a REST api.

You could write your server side code in Swift, Java or Kotlin. This would allow you to reuse some code on either iOS or Android depending on which language you chose. You could instead use Xamarin/.NET Core to write the server and both clients in C# (or F#) which would maximize your code reuse.

If you don't need or want to use a relational database, you could use MongoDB or a similar  JSON document store. You could pass those JSON documents directly to your clients. That would reduce the amount of server side code you need to write.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good link for using Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB. there are loads of samples and best practices. Information on how to secure the database. how to use partitioning correctly. Cosmos DB is really easy to implement as you don't need an ORM. it has everything built in. I am using Cosmos DB for Xamarin app I am building. It is working great so far. The best thing about it is you can scale up or down pretty easily from the azure portal. below is a good introduction and all the samples you need.

[Introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction)

[Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started)

[Samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples)

Hope this helps.